# No Blog matches the given query. DB is not removing deleted objects query number

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

**DB is not automatically removing query of deleted objects and the question is how to make it work correctly so then when I do http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/1/ it automatically shows 1st post (now it shows as if there is no post due to history of deleted objects. And if I do http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/6/ it works fine**

**Here is views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Blog

def allblogs(request):
    blogs = Blog.objects
    return render(request, 'blog/allblogs.html', {'blogs': blogs})


def detail(request, blog_id):

    try:
        question = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=blog_id)
    except Blog.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Question does not exist!!!")
    return render(request, 'blog/detail.html', {'questions': question})
```

Comment: `get_objhect_or_404` does *not* raise a `Blog.DoesNotExist`, it catches that itself, and then raises a `Http404` already.

Comment: That is totally correct and normal. The primary key is just auto incrementing. What you want would force many updates on a table just because one entry / row was deleted.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ,  Guys, I appreciate your answers but I wanna totally remove the path of deleted objects.

Comment: @MuzaffarbekMuratov: but it is really bad design to do that, especially with respect to performance and referential integrity.